# Kafka - Java - Recovering from crashs

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Here's my problem, about Kafka :

I have two programs exchanging data with Kafka (one is producing, the other is reading). Let's suppose the customer crash. The producer will keep sending messages, and after some time, we will restart the customer.

With our current broker settings, here is what is supposed to happen :

-If the crash happened less than 1 day ago (as **offsets.retention.minutes** is 1440), the offset is retrieved, and the waiting messages will be processed.

-If the crash happened more than 1 day ago , the customer's new offset will be reseted to earliest (as **auto.offset.reset** is earliest). Problem is : if some messages has already been processed (between 1 day and 7 day old), they will be again, as Kafka saves 7 days of messages (**log.retention.hours** is 168).

Is the solution as simple as setting both **offsets.retention.minutes** and **log.retention.hours** to the same value (of course, doing the conversion minutes<=>hours) ? Or will it have some side effect that I've missed ? An even simpler solution would be do just delete messages that already have been processed, but it seems Kafka can't do that.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you line of thought is correct.

I am going to quote some sentences from an interesting open issue (you can find it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3806)) to give some light about this:

About the deletion policy:

> The retention is done per topic/partition. If the last committed offset for a given topic/partition hasn't been updated for longer than offsets.retention.minutes, the offset will be garbage collected.

Reason why the default value for offset retention is that low:

> For a given consumer-group,topic,partition, after compaction, there will be only one message stored in the offset topic eventually. What we wanted to protect against is lots of short lived consumer groups.

You can have a look around the issue, you are not the first to come up with this question.